# Not able to insert data in new column

Tags: php, sql, xml

I have working code which inserts data correctly now. I am trying to add new column of movie_Id in that. I am trying to fetch the movie id value from XML and looping it with movie title but for now the data which is inserted in not correct. The `movie_name` object has 3-4 movies names. I am trying to add movie Id with that.

```
$movie_name = $arrTitle[0];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/$movie_name");
        foreach($xml->movies->movie as $movies){
      $arrMovie_id= $movies->id;
      }
      $movie_ids= $arrMovie_id[0];
    $arrStr = explode(':',$htmlShowTime);
    $release = substr($arrStr[3],0,strlen($arrStr[3])-8);
    $director = substr($arrStr[5],0,strlen($arrStr[5])-11); 

    $sql_movie = "insert into jos_movie(movie_name,language,cast,movie_release,director,rating,rating_count,movie_ids)values('$movie_name','null','$cast','$release','$director',250,230,'$movie_ids')";
```

Here is the full working code

```
<?php
// Include the handy XML data extraction functions.
include 'xml_regex.php';
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$con    =   mysql_connect('localhost','test','test');
mysql_select_db('test',$con);


// Use cURL to get the RSS feed into a PHP string variable.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'mytest.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arrData = array();
// Create an array of item elements from the XML feed.
$news_items = element_set('item', $xml);
$del_movie = "delete from jos_movie";
mysql_query($del_movie);

$del_cinema = "delete from jos_cinema";
mysql_query($del_cinema);

foreach($news_items as $item) {
    $title = value_in('title', $item);
    $url = value_in('link', $item);
    $cast = value_in('description', $item);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //$html = curl_exec($ch);
    $arrTitle = explode('-',$title);
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $htmlShowTime = '';

    // find all span tags with class=gb1 moviTimes moviTmngBox
    foreach($html->find('ul[style=line-height:2em;]') as $e)
        $htmlShowTime = $e->plaintext;

    $movie_name = $arrTitle[0];
    $arrStr = explode(':',$htmlShowTime);
    $release = substr($arrStr[3],0,strlen($arrStr[3])-8);
    $director = substr($arrStr[5],0,strlen($arrStr[5])-11); 

    $sql_movie = "insert into jos_movie(movie_name,language,cast,movie_release,director,rating,rating_count)values('$movie_name','null','$cast','$release','$director',250,230)";
    //echo $sql.'<br>';
    //echo $sql_movie;

    mysql_query($sql_movie);

    $sqlCount = 'select max(id) from jos_movie';
    $data = mysql_query($sqlCount);
    echo $data;
    print_r($data);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    $id = $result[0];
    echo '<br>'.$id.'<br>'; 

    //$id = mysql_insert_id();
    //echo $id;

        // find all span tags with class=gb1
    foreach($html->find('div.moviTmngBox') as $e){
        $tagTitle =  $e->find('a',0);
        $tagTime  = $e->find('div.moviTimes',0);
        $name = $tagTitle->title;
        $time = $tagTime->innertext;

    $trimName = '';
    $temName = strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$name));

    if(strpos($temName,'indraaudi1') !== false)
      $trimName = 'Indra Audi 1' and  $cinemaId = '1' and $long='32.726602' and $lat='74.857026';
    elseif(strpos($temName,'indraaudi2') !== false)
     $trimName = 'Indra Audi 2' and $cinemaId = '2'and $long='32.726602' and $lat='74.857026';
    elseif(strpos($temName,'indraaudi3') !== false)
      $trimName = 'Indra Audi 3'and $cinemaId = '3' and $long='32.726602' and $lat='74.857026';
    elseif(strpos($temName,'apsra') !== false)
      $trimName = 'Apsra' and $cinemaId = '4' and $long='32.700314' and $lat='74.858023';
    else{
        $trimName = trim(substr($name,18,strlen($name))) and $cinemaId = '5' and $long='32.7300' and $lat='74.8700' ;
    }

        //echo $tagTime->innertext.'<br/>';
        $sql = "insert into jos_cinema(cinema_name,show_time,movie_id,cinemaId,logitude,latitude)values('$trimName','$time',$id,$cinemaId,$long,$lat)";
        //echo $sql.'<br/>';
        mysql_query($sql);
        //$arrTem = array($tagTitle->title,$tagTime->innertext);

    }

}//end rss feed loop

?>
```

Here is my requirement.

I am getting movie names in $movie_name as an array
I have appeneded the names to xml so that I can get the moviedbId from it. I am getting the movieID successfully. I want to insert that movieDB ID to respective movie.

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: Firstly, you are using string interpolation and not prepares. (The next best thing is to use escaping). What if the server this is on ends up being MITM'd since it's not HTTPS and your site code is on SO? Also, whenever you post code, make it complete. we havent got a clue where `$htmlShowTime` is. Also, Whitespace is free. Use it!

Comment: @Hiroto Its a just a part of the code and it is working . I have added a new part to add movieID column in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

$sql = "";
foreach ($arrTitle as $movie_name) { 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/$movie_name");
    foreach ($xml->movies->movie as $movies) {
        $arrMovie_id = $movies->id;
    }
    $movie_ids = $arrMovie_id[0];
    $arrStr    = explode(':', $htmlShowTime);
    $release   = substr($arrStr[3], 0, strlen($arrStr[3]) - 8);
    $director  = substr($arrStr[5], 0, strlen($arrStr[5]) - 11);
    $sql .= "('$movie_name','null','$cast','$release','$director',250,230,'$movie_ids'),";
}
$sql       = substr($sql, 0, -1);
$sql_movie = "INSERT INTO `jos_movie`(`movie_name`,`language`,`cast`,`movie_release`,`director`,`rating`,`rating_count`,`movie_ids`) VALUES" . $sql;

?>
```

Comment: its a just a part of the entire code. if you see I am getting movies name . I am appending movie name in xml so that I can append the movieDb movieIds too with it.

Comment: I looped through the original array. At the end of the foreach, you can now do the whole query in one line.

Comment: Thanks @David I echoed the $movieids it shows 44425 44425. None of the id is correct for any movie in the array of movie_name and it echo two times :(

Comment: Can you edit your post to show a working example? What I can see is that it's searching for a movie and simply picking the first one it sees (index).

Comment: `I am getting the movieID successfully.` -- `I echoed the $movieids..None of the id is correct` -- Sorry I'm confused. Are you getting the ids correctly?

Comment: Yes when I run I got the id of the movie succesfully . The id of this movie is 10505. This is one of the movieid of the movie_name in the array
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/dabbang 2");
foreach($xml->movies->movie as $movies){
   $movie_id=$movies->id; 
}
echo $movie_id;
?>